# Expected result is not getting pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame:

```
slno                      name               class
--------------------------------------------------
0          1              sala                  12
1          2              kala                  11
2          3              amjn                  12
3          4              ajun                  10
4          5              vell                  12

import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('./student.csv', usecols=['class','slno','name'])
print(df)
df1 = df.set_index('class').T.to_dict('dict')
print(df1)
```

Current result:

```
{'12: {'slno': 1, 'name': 'sala'},
 '11': {'slno': 2, 'name': 'sala'},
 '10': {'slno': 4, 'name': 'ajun'},
```

> UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.

```
  df1 = df.set_index('class').T.to_dict('dict')
```

Expected result:

```
{'12: {'slno': 1, 'name': 'sala'},
 '11': {'slno': 2, 'name': 'sala'},
 '12': {'slno': 3, 'name': 'amjn'},
 '10': {'slno': 4, 'name': 'ajun'},
 '12': {'slno': 5, 'name': 'vell'}
}
```

Comment: Hi! The keys to python dictionaries need to be unique. What result do you expect for key 12 for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keys must be unique. You cannot have duplicate class values in your DataFrame.
Here is the expected result:
Also attached screenshot of the output.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'slno': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ['sala', 'kala', 'amjn', 'ajun', 'vell'],
    'class': [12, 11, 12, 10, 12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_function = df.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: x.drop('class', axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()

print(df_function)
```

Results:

```
{'12: {'slno': 1, 'name': 'sala'},
 '11': {'slno': 2, 'name': 'sala'},
 '12': {'slno': 3, 'name': 'amjn'},
 '10': {'slno': 4, 'name': 'ajun'},
 '12': {'slno': 5, 'name': 'vell'}
}
```

[image: result]